# Requisites to read an edmx file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, edmx

I've got an application in Visual Studio 2012 written in C# that generates code for a aspNet MVC application. I've generated the edmx file but when I try to open it, Visual Studio tells me that it was unable to display the file and asks if I want to open it with XML editor.

I also generated the appropriate "Context.cs" and "Designer.cs" files.

I manage to open other edmx files in a diagram visualization.

What I want to know is: what are the requisites to open it and see it in a diagram form? Are there support files I'm missing?

Comment: When you say you have "generated the edmx file" how did you do this? It sounds as thought the edmx file is invalid so rather than showing the designer is showing you the raw XML which is invalid.

Comment: My app receives a UML model and generates C# files (controllers, models, views, shared, webconfig, well, all needed files for a MVC solution) and an edmx. I didn't put the code here because it's too vast and without being in a context I suppose it would be really hard to understand. Yes, I know it doesn't show me the diagram because the edmx is not valid but its code is good but it still doesn't open as a diagram because of some other reason and I can't figure out

Answer (score 1):

The EDMX file is not just XML representing the database structure / mapping but also how the Visual Studio designer should render the diagram (where to place tables, associations etc).

I found [this project](https://bitbucket.org/cincura_net/edmgen2/) that creates EDMX files programatically (I have **NO** affiliation with this and found it through good ol' Google).

Answer (score 1):

Has written [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj650889.aspx):

> Entity Framework 5 uses versions 3.0 of CSDL, MSL, and SSDL specifications.

Each Visual Studio version has its own CSDL, MSL and SSDL specifications:

- Visual Studio 2008 uses EDMX v1
- Visual Studio 2010 uses EDMX v2
- Visual Studio 2012 uses EDMX v3

Have a look at the section `Changes in CSDL, MSL & SSDL 3.0 (EF5)` from the link above to see what need to be changed in your EDMX generation process to be able to open it with VS2012.